# jQuery Loop by id for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

hi i have some problem about logic of loop

have a few elements

```
<div place="1" area="Text 1" class="element"></div>
<div place="2" area="Text 2" class="element"></div>
<div place="3" area="Text 3" class="element"></div>
```

and

```
<span place="1"></span>
<span place="2"></span>
<span place="3"></span>
```

and i want to insert all div elements area attribute value to span element which place are the same

---

like this

```
<span place="1">Text 1</span>
<span place="2">Text 2</span>
<span place="3">Text 3</span>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly note that creating your own non-standard attributes in your HTML can lead to some odd behaviour. It's much better practice to use `data` attributes to store any custom metadata with an element.

To fix your actual issue, you need to loop through all the `div` elements, then select the `span` with the related `place` and set its `text()`, like this:

```js
$('.element').each(function() {
  $('span[data-place="' + $(this).data('place') + '"]').text($(this).data('area'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-place="1" data-area="Text 1" class="element"></div>
<div data-place="2" data-area="Text 2" class="element"></div>
<div data-place="3" data-area="Text 3" class="element"></div>

<span data-place="1"></span>
<span data-place="2"></span>
<span data-place="3"></span>
```

Note the use of `data-*` attributes in the example.

Comment: thanks, i want to loop few attrs of my div element also and can we loop full div and see each of div attrs and then replace

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

See below answer using jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("div[place]").each(function(i,el){
    $("span[place='"+$(this).attr("place")+"']").html($(this).attr("area"));
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div place="1" area="Text 1" class="element"></div>
<div place="2" area="Text 2" class="element"></div>
<div place="3" area="Text 3" class="element"></div>

<span place="1"></span>
<span place="2"></span>
<span place="3"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use data- attribute to make something like :

```
$( ".element" ).each(function(  ) {
  var place = $(this).attr("data-place");
  var area = $(this).attr("data-area");

  $('.place-'+place).html( area );
});
```

And your HTML structure should look that:

```
<div class="element" data-area="test 1" data-place="1"></div>
<div class="element" data-area="test 2" data-place="2"></div>
<div class="element" data-area="test 3" data-place="3"></div>


<span class="place-1"></span>
<span class="place-2"></span>
<span class="place-3"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.element').each(function(i, obj) {
    var area= $(obj).attr('area');
    var span = $('<span></span>');
    span.attr('place', i);
    span.text(area);
});
```